# Cannot detect file existing or not

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

In a program I am improving, I noticed that Fortran does not detect file existing or not. This led to a logic error which has not been fixed. I highly appreciate if you could point out the problems or errors and give me your corrections.

```
  open(unit=nhist,file=history,iostat=ierr)!This setting cannot exit program if file does not exist because ierr is always 0
  if (ierr /=0) then
   write(*,*)'!!! error#',ierr,'- Dump file not found'
   stop
  endif

  !I used below statement, the program exits even though a file is existing
       open(unit=nhist,file=history,err=700)
   700 ierr=-1
       if (ierr /=0) then
       write(*,*)'!!! error#',ierr,'- Dump file not found'
       stop
       endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct problems here.  Let's look at them separately.

First, consider

```
open(unit=nhist,file=history,iostat=ierr)
```

The comment suggests that `ierr` is always set to zero.  Well, why *shouldn't* it be set to zero?  `ierr` should be non-zero in the case the case of an error, but is the file not existing an error?

Not necessarily.  In the absence of a `status=` specifier the default `status='unknown'` is taken.  The compiler doesn't have to (and is unlikely to) treat opening in this case as an error if the file doesn't exist.  It's likely to create it as needed on a write, or complain when trying to read.

Adding `status='old'` to the `open` statement is the usual way of saying "the file should exist".

Second, consider

```
       open(unit=nhist,file=history,err=700)
   700 ierr=-1
       if (ierr /=0) then
       ...
```

If there's an error here, execution is transferred to the statement labelled `700`.  From this statement `ierr` is set to a non-zero value and off we go to the `if` construct to handle that error.

It's just that the statement labelled `700` also happens to be executed even without an error: it's simply the next statement after the `open` and there's no branch to miss it.  [I could give an example of such branching, but I don't want to encourage use of `err=` in modern code.  With the working `iostat=` things are far preferable.]

But if you just wish to test the existence of a file, consider inquire-by-file:

```
logical itexists
inquire (file=history, exist=itexists)
if (.not.itexists) error stop "No file :("
```

Some would argue this is even better than having `status='old'` in an `open` statement.

Comment: Dear Francescalus, thank you so much! Yes. It works when I add 'status=old'.