# Fortran read statement successful but calls err parameter also - why?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I ran some fortran code and it looks like it is working as it reads the appropriate line and value but then it also trips the error parameter value in the read statement.  I can't figure out why it would be doing this.  I have tinkered with this for some time and searched for answers online for a day now.  The only thing I can think is that it could be a compiler or system architecture problem.  can someone please look at a simplified version of the code below and tell me if they find an issue? The file it is reading is below as well.  Thank you.

```
 PROGRAM read

  INTEGER   :: nkfobs

  integer    :: o_unit, my_task_id, KFNVOLA
  character(len=129)   :: o_file_name, o_head_format, o_body_format
  logical    there
  DATA KFNVOLA/71/


  my_task_id = 0
  write(o_file_name, '("obs_output", i5.5)') my_task_id
  o_head_format = '(i7)'
  o_body_format = '(3f13.5,i7,f13.5)'

  INQUIRE (file=trim(o_file_name), EXIST=there)
  if( there ) then
     print *, 'opening obs file from DART'
  OPEN(KFNVOLA,FILE=trim(o_file_name),FORM='FORMATTED',STATUS='OLD')
    else
      print *, 'Error: there are no DART obs files to open'
      return
   endif

  read(KFNVOLA,fmt=o_head_format,err=19) nkfobs
  print *, 'nkfobs = ', nkfobs
19    print *, 'Error in read in o_head of subroutine inenkfobs'

  close(KFNVOLA)

  END PROGRAM read

   9230
268.25000     33.64000     82.00000      1     -0.00000
268.25000     33.64000     82.00000      2      2.57222
268.25000     33.64000     82.00000      4    302.14999
268.25000     33.64000     82.00000      5      0.01677
266.39999     34.05000    106.00000      1     -2.22761
266.39999     34.05000    106.00000      2      1.28611
266.39999     34.05000    106.00000      4    303.14999
266.39999     34.05000    106.00000      5      0.01686
268.23001     38.13000    350.00000      1     -2.31475
268.23001     38.13000    350.00000      2      2.75861
268.23001     38.13000    350.00000      4    298.14999
268.23001     38.13000    350.00000      5      0.01433
267.70001     31.40000     34.00000      1     -0.62533
267.70001     31.40000     34.00000      2      3.54640
267.70001     31.40000     34.00000      4    302.14999
267.70001     31.40000     34.00000      5      0.01665
267.97000     32.52000     24.00000      1     -0.00000
267.97000     32.52000     24.00000      2      3.60111
267.97000     32.52000     24.00000      4    302.14999
267.97000     32.52000     24.00000      5      0.01663
263.73999     32.72000    145.00000      1     -3.08667
263.73999     32.72000    145.00000      2      5.34626
263.73999     32.72000    145.00000      4    304.14999
263.73999     32.72000    145.00000      5      0.01696
```

Comment: It seems to be the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41557099): the statement labelled `19` is reached through the normal flow of execution given it won't be skipped over.

Comment: ok, its been a long time since I wrote something that used an err statement.  Where should I place the 19 statement then? I would like to keep it just in case there is a problem with the incoming file at some point.

Comment: you need a `goto` or similar construct  to jump over it, or in this example just put a `stop` after the print.