# Fortran error check on formatted read

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90

In my code I am attempting to read in output files that may or may not have a formatted integer in the first line of the file. To aid backwards compatibility I am attempting to be able to read in both examples as shown below.

```
head -n 3 infile_new
   22
           8
   98677.966601475651       -35846.869655806520        3523978.2959464169
```

or

```
head -n 3 infile_old
           8
   98677.966601475651       -35846.869655806520        3523978.2959464169       
   101205.49395364164       -36765.047712555031        3614241.1159234559
```

The format of the top line of `infile_new` is `'(i5)'` and so I can accommodate this in my code with a standard read statement of

```
read(iunit, '(I5)' ) n
```

This works fine, but if I attempt to read in `infile_old` using this, I as expected get an error. I have attempted to get around this by using the following

```
    read(iunit, '(I5)' , iostat=ios, err=110) n

110 if(ios == 0) then
      print*, 'error in file, setting n'
      naBuffer = na
      !rewind(iunit) #not sure whether to rewind or close/open to reset file position
      close(iunit)
      open (iunit, file=fname, status='unknown')
    else
      print*, "Something very wrong in particle_inout"
    end if
```

The problem here is that when reading in either the old or new file the code ends up in the error loop. I've not been able to find much documentation on using the read statement in this way, but cannot determine what is going wrong.

My one theory was my use of `ios==0` in the if statement, but figured since I shouldn't have an error when reading the new file it shouldn't matter. It would be great to know if anyone knows a way to catch such errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot detect file existing or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557099/cannot-detect-file-existing-or-not)

Comment: @francescalus: yes, a duplicate.  But OP might be forgiven for not finding it.

Comment: Hi Both, yes thanks for pointing out the similarity in using the `err` condition in the linked question and why that was causing an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown us, after the code executes the read statement it executes the statement labelled `110`.  Then, if there wasn't an error and `iostat==0` the true branch of the `if` construct is executed.

So, if there is an error in the read the code jumps to that statement, if there isn't it walks to the same statement.  The code doesn't magically know to not execute the code starting at label 110 if there isn't an error in the read statement.  Personally I've never used both `iostat` and `err` in the same read statement and here I think it's tripping you up.

Try changing the read statement to

```
read(iunit, '(I5)' , iostat=ios) n
```

You'd then need to re-work your `if` construct a bit, since `iostat==0` is not an error condition.

Incidentally, to read a line which is known to contain only one integer I wouldn't use an explicit format, I'd just use

```
read(iunit, * , iostat=ios) n
```

and let the run-time worry about how big the integer is and where to find it.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for clarifying that the labelled code is executed regardless. I got the example on how to use the `err` condition from Modern Fortran explained by Metcalf, Reid and Cohen and they've never led me astray in the past.

The issue with just using a non explicit read is that the new file is identical apart from having an extra (similar) line 1 and just reading in causes issues when reading the data below it.